# What do the different shaped dots mean on the Railway Empire minimap?

Tags: railway-empire

In "Railway Empire" (PC, via Steam), the minimap shows different icons for cities but I haven't figured out what they both mean. All cities are circles (rural businesses don't show up), but one of the cities on this map I'm playing shows up as a bigger circle with an outer ring:

[image: Minimap screenshot]

I'm playing the 'south' map on free play, and you can see that Houston is shown as a circle with a ring around it, while all the rest of the cities are shown as normal dots.

It's not my starting city (that was Corpus Christi). On other maps I've seen multiple cities indicated this way, but haven't figured out what it means.

Here's the full screenshot that I cropped the minimap out of; Houston (top left of screenshot) doesn't appear any different than any of the other cities on the map itself.

[image: Full Screenshot]

What does the dot-with-a-circle mean on the minimap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "halo" around the circle means there is a free industry slot in those cities.

According to [Steam community](https://steamcommunity.com/app/503940/discussions/0/3441214221473939640/).

Comment: Ugh thanks, my searches were failing me looking for "minimap symbols". Didn't think to call it a "halo". :-/